# Highcharts how to customize enableMouseTracking?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am currently using highcharts to display data on a line chart. I have enabled the `enableMouseTracking` option in order to be able to see the value of the point the hovers over. I am attempting to add a `%` at the end of the value. For example, my current hover over is 4.4 I would like it to show `4.4%`.

I've tried adding a percent sign to the end of values that I was using to populate the chart but that did not work so I believe I do now need to customize highchart itself. I do not see any of directly customizing the plotOptions section in the Highcharts documentation.

Currently displaying:

[image]

Would like to display: **1.8%**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {


    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        backgroundColor: '#fafafa', 
    },
    title: {
        text: stateArr.graphTitle
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017','2018'],
        title: {
            text: 'Year'
        },
    },
    credits: {
        text: stateArr.creditTitle,
        position: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            x: -20,
            y: -20
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        //categories: ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10'],
        title: {
            text: 'Percentage Change (%)'

        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            enableMouseTracking: true
        }
    },

series: [{
    name: stateArr.stateTitle,
    data: [...stRounded],
    color: '#002F65',
    custom: {
        state: stateArr.stateTitle
    },
}, {
    name: 'US',
    color: '#0B7070',
        data: [...usRounded],

    dashStyle: "DashDot",

        }],
});
```

Comment: Can u create jsfiddle example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own tooltip with the use of [tooltip.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter).

```
 tooltip: {
      borderColor: '#2c3e50',
      shared: true,
      formatter: function (tooltip) {
        //u can make your custom tooltip here
        return `<span >${this.y} <br> ${this.x}%</span><br/>`             
      }
    },
```

this is one example [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cynysyhb/) about custome tooltip